# nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment

When I'm trying to restart nginx, I'm getting the following error

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.io" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

I used my deploy scripts, to do deploying for 2 domains. For first it works fine, but for second, it gives error.

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
#
worker_processes 2;

#
user nginx nginx;

#
pid /opt/nginx/pids/nginx.pid;
error_log /opt/nginx/logs/error.log;

#
events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

#
http {
    #
    log_format full_log '$remote_addr - $remote_user $request_time $upstream_response_time '
                        '[$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent $request_body "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #
    access_log  /opt/nginx/logs/access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/cert/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/cert/example.key;

    #
    include /opt/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf;

    # Deny access to any other host
    server {
        server_name example.io;  #default
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start at the file called `nginx.conf` and look at the `server` blocks and the `include` statements. You may be reading a backup file that means `nginx` is seeing the same `server_name` on port 80 twice.

Comment: @RichardSmith I edit my question and add nginx.conf file

Comment: @RichardSmith You are right. Problem come from one of my subdomain conf file in server_name blocks and include statements.

Comment: Be carefull, there is `include sites-enable/*` in nginx.conf file loading all files in sites-enable directory. I spent two hours, I've got some auto backups parser in that directory.... I chosed to add '*.conf' extension in nginx conf.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure,but try changing server name in

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

it should help

Comment: Yes, works for me! I've try some other way to configure and I forgot to delete default. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same problem. To resolve this, I looked for conflict domain "example.io" in conf files.

In the following file, there was a snippet added for "example.io" at the bottom. "**default_server**" server section was as it is but section was added at the end of the file.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name example.io;

       root /var/www/html;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

So I think you need to search server_name in all files which reside inside "**/etc/nginx/sites-available**" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Any how your domain name is added in

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

To confirm search using

```
grep -r mydomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

and remove the domain name.

Then restart Nginx using

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Juste change listen 80 to another number like 8000 or 5000, whatever but not 80.
For good job, don't edit nginx.conf itself, create your own file.conf and link it. following this [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-symbolic-links-in-linux/). to see clearly what i means.